# Out of memory exception when using StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, streamreader

I am reading a large text file (300 MB) and converting the text into a `DataTable`, however I am getting an out of memory exception.

Code:

```
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(name)
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    While line <> Nothing

        Dim txtLines() As String = line.Split(vbTab)
        If (txtLines.Count > 0) Then
            If (i = 0) Then
                For Each item As String In txtLines
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
                Next
                i = i + 1
            Else
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row.ItemArray = txtLines
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            End If
        End If
        line = sr.ReadLine() //getting error here 
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you run out of memory. Why not bulk copy it into the database instead?

Comment: here i am loading into data table from data table i can load the the data directly into the database . every line i need to split and need to add to datatable.

Comment: Can you split it in multiple parts? You are clearly using to much memory.

Comment: do you have any sample code for this , to split multiple parts?

Comment: There are few good reasons left to still run out of memory on modern hardware.  Project > Properties > Compile tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.

Comment: i don't have that option . i have only one option for platform: any cpu

Comment: You could process (for example) 100 lines, clear the data table and continue with the next 100 lines.

Comment: yeah need to do like this . that's one of the good idea lotus..